# Shared Uploads (assets) across three models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Working on a music cataloging app.

I have three models (or levels) that make up each entry; Release, Product, Tracks.

- **Releases** can have many **Products**
- **Products** can have many **Tracks**

I want to upload files at the **Release** level that can be shared amongst its products.

For example, as user sets up a release I want them to be able to upload all related files (or assets - audio files and images) for that release. Then at the next stage, setting up a product, I want them to be able to pick and build the product from uploaded files....there is already a form for text input for the product.

Then for that product's tracklisting, again the user should be able to build this from files uploaded at the release level.

My reasoning for this approach is to avoid duplicating uploads across similar products. I could make them inherit everything from the release level but I must have the facility to alter tracklistings and images for things like limited editions. It would be great if by default they could inherit the release level files/assets and then have options to amend.

Anyway, looking for some guidance on how best to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: btw - I plan to use Paperclip for the uploads and am thinking a separate uploads model might be a step in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comparison between Paperclip, Carrierwave and Dragonfly - [CarrierWave vs. Paperclip vs. Dragonfly comparison](http://bcjordan.github.com/posts/rails-image-uploading-framework-comparison/)

If you choose [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), this will help you - [Multiple files upload with carrierwave and nested_form](http://lucapette.com/rails/multiple-files-upload-with-carrierwave-and-nested_form/)